In which Simpsons episode does this moment appear?
I'm looking for an episode of The Simpsons in which Mr. Burns is having a party and invites all his employees into his estate. When he welcomes the Simpsons he is having Smithers telling him which one is which.
Unfortunately, I don't know more about what's taking place in this episode. However, since I only know the first ~6 seasons it must be an early one.

Maybe. But I'm not sure it'll be on topic. It seems to be a gray area these days.

This is the episode “There’s no Disgrace Like Home”, S1E4. 

After being embarrassed by the rest of the family at a company picnic,
  Homer becomes obsessed with improving their behavior towards each
  other.

The scene you are talking about is 2m44s into this clip:



